# How might I find all functions that have a power series whose coefficients are all 1 or -1.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose I have that

$f(x)= \pm 1 \pm x \pm x^2 \cdots$

How can I find $f(x)$?

Specifically, I know I'm looking for all functions such that $|f^{k}(0)|=k!$, which functions are those?

Which functions have the property that $|f^{k}(x_0)|=k!$ for some $x_0 \neq 0$?

Comment: Do you mean $|f^{(k)}(0)|=k!$ instead?

Comment: Do you mean that either every coefficient is $1$ or every coefficient is $-1$, or that every coefficient can be either $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Every coefficient can be either -1 or 1 but not zero.

Comment: There are an awful lot of them-uncountably many in fact.

Comment: Wouldn't it be countably many? The functions that have the property of $|f^k(0)|=k!$ are precisely the functions of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \pm x^k$ unioned with the littlewood polynomials (Call the union of these sets $S$). So we can construct an isomorphism that changes the -1 coefficients to 0's and concatenates them into a binary string.We can then convert the binary string to decimals and get a bijective mapping:

$\phi: S \to N$

$\phi(a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n)=$ dec $(a_0a_1 \ldots a_n)$

So $\phi(1+x-x^2+x^3)=$ dec $(1101)=13$